# Flask-SocketIO not receiving data

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, chat

I am trying to send filename of uploaded photo using flask-socketio, but it doesn't work. It runs without error and prints room and photo_filename variables correctly but client does not receive data in room.

```
@socketio.on('send_photo')
def send_photo(photo_filename, room):
    print(photo_filename)
    print(room)
    emit({'msg': photo_filename}, room=room, namespace="/")
```

This is another function that runs fine and client gets the data:

```
@socketio.on('message')
def message(data):
    now = datetime.now()
    send({'msg': data['msg'].encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'), 'username': data['username'], 'time_stamp': now.strftime("%H:%M  %d.%m.%Y")}, room=data['room'], namespace="/")
```

Does anybody know why the second function works and the first does not? Thanks.

Comment: does the client receive no data? does he receive falsified data? I would enable the debugger to have more info.

Comment: if using the func 'message' client gets all data correcly, but when you calling the func 'send_photo' client gets no data...

Comment: also maybe be try : "socketio.emit" instead of emit

Comment: and enabling debugger would help tremendously regardless

Comment: I tried with same result

Comment: Debugger shows no problems

Comment: whats the client code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem. I was passing an integer to the room variable but it must be a string.

```
@socketio.on('send_photo')
def send_photo(photo_filename, room):
    print(photo_filename)
    print(room)
    emit({'msg': photo_filename}, room=str(room), namespace="/")
```